# Is there a way to collect data about edit descriptions?

Tags: discussion, edit-summary

I've seen people connecting various aspects of questions asked over time (especially with [tags](http://graphoverflow.com/graphs/stackoverflow-tag-relations.html), which is no doubt the easiest thing to work with) and being able to make some fun graphs or charts appear, or develop a greater understanding about the [community of coders](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/).

Now, I've not been on SO for very long and I'm still learning about how it works, but I think it would be extremely useful to investigate **descriptions of edits** to look for the most common reasons for edits occurring. With information like this, we can see what kind of mistakes people are making in asking their questions and use those to try and filter out bad question asking habits. You can't do a whole lot with "Fixed typos and grammar" or something like that, but if we start seeing a lot of "Moved code into code block" edits then I think it would be quite clear that that functionality is underused, or misunderstood maybe.

That's quite an obvious answer - you see questions with edits about code blocks all the time. But I think that monitoring the kind of edits people are suggesting would reveal some interesting new habits people have arrived with and help to single out areas in which users should focus to make their questions better.

Of course, one could argue that to know how to write a good question, *just follow the guidelines!* But I think we all know that, for whatever reason, there are always going to be bad questions. I think that by identifying in particular what the *community's* suggestions are towards making questions better, we can learn a lot about what people see as a good question.

It's just a thought - I'm not sure how feasible it is to search through edit descriptions for common occurrences of certain words or phrases, or maybe it's even been done already. It was something I've not been able to find any info about and thought I would raise it just in case it helps. Thanks!

Comment: You're very generously assuming that everyone fills in the edit descriptions. That isn't my experience. I rarely do, unless I have something important to say. If it's something I consider to be an obvious grammar, spelling, or formatting edit, I leave it blank and let the system auto-generate some nonsense comment.

Comment: I didn't actually realise that the system auto-generated edit messages - are they human-readable and relevant or is it just machine talk? Depending on how accurate they are it could still be usable, and I'd argue that probably the most interesting problems are the ones where you *do* feel that you have to leave a message.

Comment: It says "added x characters in body" or "removed x characters in body" or "edited tags" or something like that. They're (usually) accurate, but they're not at all meaningful. And yes, the interesting problems are the ones where I feel I have to leave a message, like the ones where I fix bugs in people's answers and I feel the need to leave a justification. These special cases would not be useful or instructive to others. (Also, [some users just ramble about incoherent nonsense in edit summaries](https://superuser.com/users/307/random?tab=activity&sort=revisions).)

Comment: You can use the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get this information.  IIRC it is the PostHistory table that contains the revisions and their comments.

Comment: @Cody IIRC those with less than 2k rep are required to submit an edit comment.

Comment: Yes, that's true, @Tiny. I recall running into that limitation periodically on sites where I am a mere peon. :-) But that doesn't change that the majority of these descriptions are still "improved formatting" (even when it doesn't touch the formatting—argh!).

Comment: @Cody Oh sorry, not negating that, just throwing it out there for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you'll find the [posthistory table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) and in that a column called `comment` which contains the edit description when the posthistorytypeid = 5 (edited body) (4 = edited title and 6 = edited tags).

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/688701) gives you an idea of what you'll find:

```sql
select comment
     , count(*)
from posthistory
where posthistorytypeid = 5 -- body
and comment not like '%characters in body%' -- I may hope Jeff didn't fix this
group by comment
order by count(*) desc
```

When run today this will be your result:

[image]

Keep in mind that the SQL Server instance SEDE is running on only allows queries to run for 2 minutes. Specially for analyzing huge amounts of rows that require full table scan will often not allow you enough time for the query to complete. If limiting your search scope is not possible, you can consider to download the [Datadump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps/224922#224922) and load the data in your own tooling and run it on your own hardware to overcome earlier mentioned limits.

Comment: Is the Jeff comment about the pluralization (1 character vs 1 characters)? [Giant S incoming](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Unfortunately, what Cody was saying seems to be true - a lot of generic, plain summaries that wouldn't be particularly helpful in identifying specific recurring problems. A shame, but good to know - at the end of the day I see why you wouldn't usually need to bother with writing elegant, informative summaries when edits usually speak for themselves, and that's what users are going to be paying attention to. I'm going to play around with this though to see if I can't glean anything interesting.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/852953/is-there-a-way-to-collect-data-about-edit-descriptions someone had a gripe